# What does "..[method of] training a deep autoencoder is to greedily pretrain the deep architecture by training a stack of shallow autoencoders" mean?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, time-series

I am working a huge project, and one of the data pipelines I'm including will include a system of stacked autoencoders, the idea of which I got from a research paper I read recently. Since I'm preparing my whitepaper for the initial framework, I have been studying all the different things I need to understand deeply before beginning to code, and I stumbled upon this phrase in 'Deep Learning' by Ian Goodfellow et. al. and is the only reference I have read so far about deep or stacked autoencoders.

So what exactly are they saying here as far as structure and methodology because I find the wording very confusing?

Also, could someone please help me identify the differences between stacked autoencoders and deep autoencoders and any information you can provide on both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's my understanding of it: an autoencoder detects features without explicit labels. It's a technique for unsupervised learning. From http://ufldl.stanford.edu/wiki/index.php/Stacked_Autoencoders

[image]

Intuitively, it is trying to detect 4 (`h1-h4`) features from X, and then try to reconstruct X with an estimate `Xhat`, from the 4 detected features.

Now if you put the h detected features as an input to another auto-encoder, you're effectively "stacking" auto-encoders, like the following:

[image]

So intuitively, this is trying to detect more features within the previously detected features. This is therefore "greedy" or "greedily stacking shallow (only 2 layers) auto-encoders". Historically this stacking and training the shallow auto-encoders is computationally faster than training auto-encoders with 4-5 layers directly.

Sorry for imprecise language, just trying to provide an intuition. I'm learning also.

Comment: Awesome answer, thank you! Now the stacked autoencoders are computationally faster you said, but is there a better understanding of the features in a direct deep autoencoder or is the learned feature set roughly the same?

Comment: Typically (deep) auto-encoders are only trained greedily (stacked) with thin layers. I believe this is because it is difficult to converge to an estimate of outputs which reconstruct the inputs from a _small_ set of features, especially when it is multi-layered. I've removed the deeplearning4j picture and edited the answer a bit because it's probably confusing, since that picture is referring to auto-encoders with RBM (Restricted Boltzmann Machines) layers.

Comment: Thank you! I did some more research actually looking into actual implementations, which, along with this answer helped a lot.